# how to maintain user session between 2 different web applications?

Tags: java, session, salesforce, tomcat8, usersession

We have 2 websites, One is developed on Salesforce with logged in functionality where the logged in user gets his personalised content.
The other website is Java application on Tomcat server with **no logged in functionality.**

Both websites will be hosted on the single domain, and for the user, there won't be many changes in terms of look & feel.  However, during the entire user journey, we want to persist the user session so that he doesn't have to log in again on the 1st website.

Also, though the Java application doesn't have the logged functionality, we would like to pass some user details to Java application and present some targeted content (not the personalized).

Can someone suggest how can we achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Redis. Store your session from salesforce application and use the same session to access second application. We schive with Microservices architectures.
This may get you some idea.

[https://medium.com/@odedia/spring-session-redis-part-i-overview-a5f6c7446c8b]

Thanks